# HTACCESS Rewrite url how to delete variable ?go=

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have a Url like:

> http://URL.com/go.php?go=AZERTYUIP

I Want to change it to:

> http://URL.com/AZERTYUIP

I don't know how to do it using htaccess.

Comment: just for your information i use a selfwritten php class to handle the rewriting and just send everything through my index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]*)$ /?go=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

something like that should do the trick

to learn more about htaccess and regex simply use google.

ALSO on using links dont reffer them to the /?go=abc anymore but just planely to: /abc

Comment: let me take a look at how i did it

Comment: edited the code this might do the trick, it does the trick for me

Comment: Thanks Anyway  im sure i will use it one day :)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/?$        index.php?&slug=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [PT]
```

index.php

```
<?php
include ($_GET['slug'].'.php');
?>
```